# Changing layout output DPI and dimensions using QGIS Python

Tags: qgis, python, print-composer, layout-manager, dpi

I would like to use Python to change the DPI of my map image files, I am not sure where in my code I need to add this line.

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.core import QgsPrintLayout
from qgis.core import QgsLayoutExporter
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                       QgsLayoutSize
                       )
from qgis import processing


project = QgsProject.instance()             
manager = project.layoutManager()           
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)          
layoutName = "PrintLayout"

layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
for layout in layouts_list:
    if layout.name() == layoutName:
        manager.removeLayout(layout)
        
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()               
layout.setName(layoutName)
manager.addLayout(layout)

from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()     


countrylist = ['Africa', 'Asia', 'Caribbean', 'World map', 'Europe', 'Middle East', 'Oceania', 'South America', 'North America']

for i in countrylist:
    layout = manager.layoutByName(f'{i}')        
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    exporter.exportToImage(f'D:/Sanch/Work/Automate/{today} {i}.png', QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `settings` object which accesses the [ImageExportSettings](https://qgis.org/api/structQgsLayoutExporter_1_1ImageExportSettings.html) of the `QgsLayoutExporter` object. You can then modify the attributes of the `settings` object as desired, and pass it as the second argument to the `exportToImage()` method. See below for a minimal example (in your case you would declare the `settings` object and set its attributes inside your for loop).

```py
project = QgsProject().instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('layout_name')

exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
settings = exporter.ImageExportSettings()
settings.dpi = 150

path = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\test_layout_image.png'

exporter.exportToImage(path, settings)
```